# PHP Sessions across domains and shared multiple domains

Tags: php, session, ssl, cookies, https

I am trying to set up the following:

```
login.domain.com
site1.domain.com
site2.domain.com
https://domain2.com
```

where if the user visits site1.domain.com or site2.domain.com and they are not logged in, they redirect to login.domain.com/?url=site1.domain.com

On php aplication domain.com. Im set up php.ini session using redis.

```
session.save_handler=redis
session.save_path="tcp://127.0.0.1:6379?weight=1&database=14"
```

After authentication success. Im set cookie session_id.

On site1.domain.com and site2.domain.com .Im get Cookie

```
$sessionid = $_COOKIE['session_id'];
session_id($sessionid);
session_start();
```

User login success.

But I have problem. How to domain2.com get cookie, domain https SSL access it and security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is pass the session directly in the URL. So when you link to `domain2.com` you pass the session like so (assuming you haven't changed your session ID handler from the default)

```
domain2.com?PHPSESSID=[your session ID here]
```

While there are some potential security risks (I would regenerate IDs at key points if I were you), it could solve your problem.

Another solution would be to hash the session ID and store that in your Redis instance, then set the session based on that hash. A bit more secure that way.